# Orders that have not yet been paid mysql

Tags: mysql

I am stuck with the following problem: I would like to return from my query the orders which have yet to be paid with the amount of the order and my customer information.

Here is what the tables look like:

[image]

Taking the case of customer number 124. I can see that this one has placed 13 orders. But I only have 7 checks registered

[image]

[image]

And I can see that if I add the sum of the orders minus the sum of the payments I find a difference that corresponds to the last 3 orders that this customer has placed.

[image]

So the question is how do I bring out the commands 10382, 10371, 10368 with all that? Knowing that the solution must be able to be applied to all orders.

So I thought to myself maybe using the order and payment dates. What orders does my customer place between their last payment and today?

So I tried something like this

```
#last order date
WITH last_cmd AS
(
    SELECT
        customerNumber, od.orderNumber, orderDate last_orderDate, 
        shippedDate, SUM(quantityOrdered * priceEach) totcmd
    FROM
        orders o
    LEFT JOIN
        orderdetails od ON o.orderNumber = od.orderNumber
    WHERE
        status NOT LIKE 'Can%'
    GROUP BY
        orderDate
    ORDER BY
        customerNumber, orderDate DESC
),
#last payment date last_payment AS
(
    SELECT
        customerNumber, amount, paymentDate, checkNumber
    FROM
        payments
    GROUP BY
        paymentDate
    ORDER BY
        customerNumber, paymentDate DESC
)
SELECT *
FROM last_cmd lc
LEFT JOIN last_payment lp ON lc.customerNumber = lp.customerNumber
GROUP BY lc.orderNumber
HAVING MAX(paymentDate) NOT BETWEEN MAX(last_orderDate) AND NOW();
```

[image]

But as you can see the result is not really what is expected. Still taking customer 124 as an example, command 10382 does not appear. And when I do the comparison of other orders manually for other customers the results do not match.

Does anyone have an idea please?

Here is the query I tried before posting

```
WITH ALL_PAYMENTS AS (
WITH paymentsValues AS (
select customerNumber, checkNumber, YEAR(paymentDate) paymentYear, sum(amount) paymentValue
from payments
LEFT JOIN customers USING (customerNumber) 
GROUP BY customerNumber, paymentYear)
SELECT 
    customerNumber,
    checkNumber,                        #Cumul des commandes clients
    paymentYear,
    SUM(paymentValue) totalPaymentsValue
FROM
    paymentsValues
GROUP BY 
    customerNumber, 
    checkNumber
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING checkNumber is null),

ALL_ORDERS AS(
WITH ordersValues AS (
select customerNumber, orderNumber, YEAR(orderDate) orderYear, sum(quantityOrdered*priceEach) AS orderValue 
from orderdetails 
LEFT JOIN orders USING (orderNumber) 
GROUP BY orderNumber, orderYear)
SELECT 
    customerNumber,
    orderNumber,                #Cumul des commandes clients
    orderYear,
    SUM(orderValue) totalOrderValue
FROM
    ordersValues
#where orderNumber = '10179'
GROUP BY 
    customerNumber, 
    orderNumber 
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING orderNumber is null)

SELECT AO.customerNumber, totalOrderValue, totalPaymentsValue, totalOrderValue-totalPaymentsValue Diff
FROM ALL_ORDERS AO 
LEFT JOIN ALL_PAYMENTS AP ON AP.customerNumber=AO.customerNumber 
WHERE totalOrderValue-totalPaymentsValue > 0;
```

Comment: How should anybody know what you didn't understood? Are you facing any problem with the given query?

Comment: Well, I'd like to understand how do you really consider a payment is done and which one is pending?
It'd be easy to understand if you could be more specific about the structure of the database.

Comment: I dont think this data structure will work if a customer has more than one order. You may wish to rethink the schema here

Comment: Hello sorry I probably misspoke I'm new to mysql.
I want to return order number that have not been paid by the customer. As well as the customer concerned. I have four different type of status and I want to return all my orders that are not canceled and where the amount is different from the amount of the order.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Since your payments do not contain any information which order they are paying off, you will have a hard time doing a join like that. Probably more complicated if customers pay 2 invoices at once, or 1 invoice with 2 payments. You may want to compare the sum due and the sum paid, and if they don't match, maybe pick the newest invoices, or something.

Comment: @Solarflare Yes you are absolutely right that is indeed the case. I edited my post to make it clearer.

Comment: "But as you can see the result is not really what is expected". No, this can not be seen from the info you supplied because you did not show what to expect. How should we know how order 10382 looks like ? Or if order 12345 should be in the list ?

Comment: @Luuk Well you can see in the second image that the order 10382 was registered after 10371

Comment: Generally speaking, this process is called "clearing". You will usually have a (or some) table to keep track of which open items connect to which open items - not only payments to order, but also to credit memos, write offs, ... Automatic systems (and also humans) usually use dates, payment amount, account holder, information from the note to payee lines (which oftentimes refer to the invoice(s) to be paid by this), ... to do this. I'd try to add such a logic to your system, otherwise you'd have to make this every time on the fly (as you currently try to do).

Comment: @Solarflare yes i understand what you say but the thing is i am not the one who created the database i am just using it and forbidden to modify it ^^"

Comment: Which is why my first comment was: "sum up all payments, sum up all invoices, if they don't match, show him and the latest invoices (that sum up to the missing amount)." This will probably be as accurate as anything you can come up with matching invoices on the fly in a single query, as any deviation from the simplest form of "unique payment amounts paid in full in one payment each" will make things significantly more complicated. Possible, but complicated. (Maybe identify the customer and then run a procedure to do the matching according to some rules.)

Comment: @Solarflare Yes indeed you are right and it was something that I had already considered with a request that I made previously but I wanted to see if it was possible to accomplish everything in one request and obviously I do not see this solution. I'm going to edit my post so you can see the request I envisioned earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give a list op amount that have to be paid, per date:

```
WITH d as (
    select distinct orderDate as `date` from orders
    union
    select distinct paymentDate as `date` from payments)
select
   `date`,
   `customerNumber`,
   `ordersValue`,
   `amountPayed`,
   `ordersValue` - `amountPayed` NotPayed
from (
   select
      d.`date` as "date", 
      o.customerNumber as "customerNumber",
      sum(quantityOrders*priceEach) ordersValue,
      (select sum(amount) 
       from payments p 
       where o.customerNumber = p.customerNumber AND p.paymentDate <= d.`date`) as amountPayed
   from orderdetails od
   cross join d 
   inner join Orders o on od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber AND o.orderDate <= d.`date`
   group by d.`date`, o.customerNumber
) orderListPerCustomer
WHERE `customerNumber` = 124 
ORDER BY `date` DESC
;
```

- It is impossible to add order info, because there is no order info in the payments
- This query does not take into account the status of the order (which might be `Cancelled`)

NOTE: This code is not tested, so there could be typing errors...

Comment: Sounds really interesting! If we could just select the last items from the last time where the difference between the sum of orders and payments was zero I think that would really do the trick. Thanks for your help I'll try to explore this trail =)